# Add user to default "Users" group

Tags: powershell

I have this Configuration resource:

```
User DefaultUser {
    Username = $Credential.UserName
    Password = $Credential
    Ensure = "Present"
    PasswordChangeNotAllowed = $true
    PasswordNeverExpires = $true
}
```

The user is created but not added to the default Users group. How can I ensure that the user is added to the default Users group, also must support localization. For example in Norwegian the Users group is named Brukere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DSC [Group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282124.aspx) Resource:

```
Group UserGroup{
  GroupName = "S-1-5-32-545"
  Ensure = "Present"
  MembersToInclude = $Credential.UserName
  Credential = $adminCredential
}
```

I could not actually test this but i inspected the resource and found that it uses

```
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($principalContext, $GroupName);
```

to get the group.

Microsofts documentation on this method ([FindByIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359434(v=vs.110).aspx)) states that the identity can be of any value contained in [IdentityType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356425(v=vs.110).aspx), so we can take care of localization by using the SID.

Here you can find a listing of well known SIDs if you want to use this method for adding to other Groups: [Well-Known SID Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980032.aspx)